# Monospaced font to align text using spaces makes it look odd

Tags: css, fonts, monospace

I was using the default html font - `Liberation Serif—30 glyphs` in my  page. Then i faced a problem, that multiple spaces to align two columns of text is not working properly.

I found out, spaces are not displayed at the same width as other characters and hence the same number of characters doesn't use same width. so, i started using monospaced font. It solves the alignment problem.

The alignment looks good now but the font is not the commonly used one as per the corporate standards.

How can i use a font like Liberation Serif and still do alignment using space characters?

Comment: The mono tag does not refer to monospaced text; refer to its tag info

Comment: You can but this is a REALLY bad way of aligning text. You should find a better way to align your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align text in columns, how about using a `<table>`? Or if it's not tabular data, some CSS and `float: left;`.

Answer (score 1):

To use a monospace font for primitive formatting in **HTML**, you can use the `<pre> ... </pre>` element. In fact, this tag will automatically select a monospace font for you:

```
<!-- the following shows the HTML, and the output will have the same column 
     formatting as it appears between the 'pre' tags -->
<pre>
      9      328
  2,345      208
    xyz        4
</pre>
```

`<pre>` stands for "preserve." You can also apply it as a **css** style to other types of HTML tags. In this case, you would need to explicitly specify the monospace (such as "Consolas" on Windows) font to use:

```
<div style='font-family:Consolas; white-space:pre;'>
      9        a
  2,345      quick
    xyz      f o x
</div>
```

Make sure the text editor you use to create the HTML file is set to insert <kbd>space</kbd> characters. The layout might not look the same in the browser if it has any <kbd>tab</kbd> characters, or a mixture of <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd>.

Also, since the column ***and row*** formatting of the entire text inside a `<pre>` tag is preserved exactly, the examples shown above this would include an initial "line break" ***before the first row*** which (unlike the final line break) you might not want. It's because the text that's included actually starts ***immediately after*** the `>` character of the opening tag. There a few ways to address this, which are left as an exercise for the reader.